# On my local SQL Server 2014 it works fine on the remote server I get this

Tags: sql-server

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'Apartamente.dbo.ProductType'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

Comment: Why do I get the above error

Comment: [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

[image]You are created a column with `not null` field.

Change it to `allow null` in your field property.

like this:

[image]

Comment: I have to have the id column as PK so why it works on local server and not on a remote server. The identity is set to yes and increment by 1. Any suggestion please?

Comment: No I do not. But still it doesn't

Comment: ApartamenteEntities db = new ApartamenteEntities();
                
                db.ProductTypes.Add(productType);
                db.SaveChanges();

Comment: remove your id first, then create a new one.. then on property below click identity from no to yes..

Answer (score 0):

My Guess:

It's because on your local server the column "id" must be an identity column and on the remote server it's not.

Comment: how do i set it?

Comment: in management studio you click design on the table and the select the column and change the identity field to yes in the properties of the column.  If you do it by t-sql then you have to either 1. Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table 2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductType](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]